# How would I create new edges around an opening

Tags: modeling, edges

What method would you use to create new edges around this doorway maintaining it's shape? (desired outcome in red)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can select the edges around the doorway, duplicate them, seperate the edges, increase the seperation's size, and Knife Project that separation onto the mesh in question.